# Difference between Bootstrap versions in validation

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I updated my Bootstrap version and now I am in trouble with validated fields.

Version 2.3.4 everything is working fine:

[Bootstrap CSS on version 2.3.4](http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/anxmv/2/)

```
<form name="form" ng-app>
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.email.$invalid]">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Your email address</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required />
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
```

But with the latest version required fields are not working anymore, no red field when validation error etc:

[Bootstrap CSS on version 3.3.4](http://jsfiddle.net/sanurmi/f0h6kkww/2/)

**Question**

How to change the code to get those fields working like before?

Comment: Have a look at Bootstrap 3' documentation and you'll see that your HTML doesn't match the new layout. For example, `controls` should now be `form-group` and every input should have this class `form-control`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working version with the latest Bootsrap + AngularJS](http://jsfiddle.net/sanurmi/f0h6kkww/5/)

```
<form name="form" ng-app>

<div class="col-md-4" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.email.$invalid && !form.email.$pristine }">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="rma.Addressid.email" placeholder="email" required>
    <p ng-show="form.email.$invalid && !form.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
</div>
    <hr/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
```

Comment: can you also highlight the changes you did so others who find this question and the answer get benefited ?

Comment: There is that jsfiddle where is the old version and the new version beneath it. There is basically changes in every row except label and button. http://jsfiddle.net/sanurmi/f0h6kkww/5/

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form" ng-app>
    <div class="form-group has-error" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.email.$invalid]">
        <label for="email">Your email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="email" required />
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is how your HTML should look with Bootstrap 3. 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

Comment: Color changing from red to blue is missing in your snippet. I will read the documentation and update my code. This is much bigger work what I was thinking about, I have something like 10 forms waiting for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The way forms work in newer Bootstrap version has changed since version 2.x.x. If you look at the docs and compare, it will become evident.

There are couple of new classes like `has-errror` or `has-success` instead of just `error` or `success`

Also, the `input` in the form needs to have the class `form-control` to make it work in Bootstrap 3.x.x.

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0h6kkww/3/) with minimal changes to make it work but you should definitely look at [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#forms) and change your HTML structure.

Comment: But there is no validation or red borders in the field when validation error in your updated fiddle? I will check the documentation...

Comment: It does for me - https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/222220/0HqK9qZaihPJyrCvPJ4yCpyqc2vrObeo

Comment: Strange. http://oi58.tinypic.com/243far7.jpg Chrome as a web browser. I will check examples and docs and try to solve this. Argh! Yours is after submitting...I wanted it to be like realtime as well. My mistake.

Comment: @Sami to be real-time you'd have to tell AngularJS to listen to the inputs key change and add the corresponding class `has-error` `has-success` and so on.. similar to what jquery does with `.change()`

Comment: @Vlad57 I wonder why it worked before with older Bootsrap version.

Comment: @Sami , that's an interesting question. Might be that Bootstrap did that for you.. but they've changed it in Bootstrap 3 and you have to do it instead.

Comment: @Sami: Nice :+1: Maybe you should add this as an answer as well, for future folks having the same issue :)